# How many process builder can be used in sandbox?

Tags: process-builder, governorlimits

Max how many process builder, approval process, workflows can be used in sandbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can refer the limit documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits.htm&language=en_US)

> Total active rules and active processes per object is 50

Rules include workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, and auto-assignment rules.